# Steps to implement thesaurus in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text, thesaurus, containskey

Can anyone help me with steps for how to implement thesaurus search in oracle 11g.
I have read the oracle text document but it was of no help.

Comment: **Do not vote to close**  This question is not too broad.  Oracle Text already contains thesaurus logic, and there is probably a relatively simple way to make this work.

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/cthes.htm

Comment: Also, an example here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1097936?start=0&tstart=0